# What data type should I use for variable length with German characters?

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird, firebird-embedded

What data type should I use for variable length with German characters?

I'm not sure the following is ok.

```
public const string stFIELD_DEFINITIONS = " fstInfo VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS, fiKeyID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ";
```

"VARCHAR(x) CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS" is described as "fixed length" per https://firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-data-types.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VARCHAR` is not fixed-length, it only has a maximum length. It looks like a copy and paste error from the entry of `nchar` three lines above.

However that said, instead of `UNICODE_FSS`, you should use `UTF8`. The difference is that `UNICODE_FSS` is restricted to 1-3 bytes UTF-8 (the so called 'file system safe'-set), while `UTF8` allows the full range. That  document seems to be a bit outdated to be honest, for example the equivalent of `bigint` is `BIGINT`, not `INT64`, and unique identifier would be better as a `CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS` together with the [UUID functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-uuid)